# How to destroy columns mistakenly created by Paperclip in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

As the title suggests, I accidentally add some random attachment columns to my model. Say I did `rails generate paperclip portfolio href`

How do I remove those columns created? `rails destroy paperclip portfolio href` doesnt seem to work!

Comment: Does the generator create a migration file?

Comment: Sure. But I can't revert this by using the `destory` counterpart.

Answer (score 8):

For recent version rails 4++ 
Just create a migration
 Example:

`rails g migration remove_attachment_photo_to_course` 
Then open the migration file

```
class RemoveAttachmentPhotoToCourse < ActiveRecord::Migration                                                                                                                                                                             
  def change                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    remove_attachment :courses, :photo                                                                                                                                                                                                   
  end                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
end
```

Then run, to update the table

```
rake db:migrate
```

Where: 
photo is the name of paperclip attachment you want to remove
courses is the name of table name

Answer (score 6):

I have created a migration file and change the content to:

```
class RemoveAttachmentHrefToPortfolios < ActiveRecord::Migration   
  def self.up
    remove_attachment :portfolios, :href   
  end

  def self.down
    remove_attachment :portfolios, :href   
  end 
end
```

The problem is it is not the elegant and correct way to do it. I hope someone can improve this answer..

Answer (score 1):

Normally for a migration you run `rake db:rollback`. Since this was a generator, you can just manually edit the table and drop the columns.

```
alter table portfolio drop column href_content_type;
alter table portfolio drop column href_file_name;
-- ... etc for each of the Paperclip columns.
```

You could also create a migration to drop the columns, but that would be overkill unless your whole team also ran the generator or you checked in schema.rb and others ran it also.

Here is an example migration for removing columns:

```
class RemoveMagazineFromBooks < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    # This is not used ANYWHERE...
    if column_exists? :refinery_books, :magazine
      remove_column :refinery_books, :magazine
      remove_index :refinery_books, :magazine if index_exists? :refinery_books, :magazine
    end
  end
end
```

Notice the test to check if the column is there. Some people may not have run the previous migration and will not have the column.

Comment: It is a good solution! But I am afraid that I might need a solution using migration. I have came up with a solution. It is very dumb since i do not understand `self.up` and `self.down`. Do you mind giving me some advice over that?

Answer (score 1):

This comes from the Paperclip [documentation](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#migrations):

```
remove_attachment :portfolios, :href
```

Answer (score 1):

This will rollback the latest changes to the DB schema:

```
rake db:rollback
```

After that, simply delete the migration file.

This is presuming that you didn't commit any of the changes/migrations to a shared repository.

Answer (score 0):

`$ rails generate migration RemoveColumnsFromModel portfolio href`

should make you a migration that will remove two columns "href" and "portfolio" from some model's table.  The migration will look something like:

```
class RemoveColumnsFromUser < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    remove_column :users, :foo, :string
    remove_column :users, :bar, :string
  end
end
```